# How to bring back the texthint upon entering a word or pressing the add button within an edittext?

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml

Everytime I press add button or the enter of keyboard for adding a player name to my listview, the entered name remains. I want it to be that once you press enter/or the add button. This part goes back to the original hint text (in my case that is player ...)

See code below:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewlayout, 
R.id.list_content, list);
    Lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    final EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Playername);
    class MyKeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                if (Name.length() > 0) {
                    list.add(name);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    Name.setOnKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            if (Name.length() > 0) {
                list.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                ;
            }
        }
    });

    Reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.clear();

        }
    });

    Sgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!list.isEmpty())
                openActivity2();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think , you forgot to add

`Name.setText("");` after adding it to list.

use,

```
       if (name.length() > 0) {
            list.add(name);
            Name.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `ENTER` key code and your add button code.

```
 editText.getText().clear();
```

Or you can you this line of code instead.

```
 editText.setText("");
```